# How to Sending form text input to console.log?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I have a form with three field. I need to have the info the user types in sent to console.log for now. Is this possible and if so what would I write?

modal.blade.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="level-show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Level</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="{{ route('postInsertLevel') }}" method="POST" id="form-level-create">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <select name="program_id" id="program_id" class="form-control">

                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="level" id="new-level" class="form-control" placeholder="Level">
                            <br>
                            <input type="text" name="description" id="new-description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description level">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-save-level">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
    $('#level-click').on('click', function(){
        var programs = $('#program_id option');
        var program = $('#form-level-create').find('#program_id');
        $(program).empty();
        $.each(programs, function(i, pro) {
            $(program).append($("<option>",{
                value : $(pro).val(),
                text : $(pro).text()
            }))
        })
        $('#level-show').modal();
    });
    $('#form-level-create').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url, data, function(data){
            console.log(data)
        })
    });
```

TestController.php

```
public function postInsertLevel(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return response(Level::create($request->all()));
        }
    }
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/manager/course/insert-level', ['as' => 'postInsertLevel', 'uses' => 'CourseController@postInsertLevel']);
```

But I try to display console.log I see:

[image: Console.log]

Comment: where is your #level-click button ?

Comment: Their is some part of you code missing, difficult to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well what you want but, it is what you want to do ?

```js
function print(){
  var choice = document.getElementById('1').value;
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = choice;
  console.log(choice);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="1">
    <option>Banana
    <option>Apple
    <option>Orange
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return print();">
</form>
<p id="2"></p>
```

Comment: I did not understand anything?

Comment: @Mahoumoud Khosravi is that what you want ? 
When you return false in a submit button it cancel the form request.
And i just pick the value from my <input> and write it in the <p>.
Tell me if others incomprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you routing through Laravel? You could simply add events listeners in your client JavaScript for 'keyup' to your form fields and console.log the event payload.

Also, why not use server side logging? `logger($input)` in your controller, for example.